# Best practice to handle the paging and performance in SQL Stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I am using MS SQL stored procedure to retrieve data and display it in the GRID. My problem is that the stored procedure has complex queries and it returns a total of 12K records. But in the grid am exposing 1st 50 records only.

I have used SQL fetch and offset concept to avoid the unwanted data but I want the total count to display it in the grid.

Can you please suggest any better solution to handle this?

Comment: http://andreyzavadskiy.com/2016/12/03/pagination-and-total-number-of-rows-from-one-select/

Comment: @MatthewEvans thanks for sharing the details, I have already checked this blog, my problem is we are performing filtering and sorting too so taking count as mentioned in this sample is not works

Comment: You should add these details and what you have tried to your question

Answer (score 1):

In global you can build such a structure:

```
create PROCEDURE your_sp                                                               
    @PageNumber  INT           = 1,
    @PageSize    INT           = 10,

    DECLARE @lPageSize INT= @PageSize;
    DECLARE @lFirstRecord INT= (@lPageNumber - 1) * @lPageSize;
    DECLARE @lLastRecord INT= (@lPageNumber * @lPageSize + 1);

    CREATE TABLE #tmp (...)

    INSERT INTO #tmp (

    select * from 

    (... your sub select heer)

    WHERE ROWNUM > @lFirstRecord
        AND ROWNUM < @lLastRecord

     )


-- Count all results in temporary table
        DECLARE @COUNT BIGINT;
         SET @COUNT =
         (
             SELECT COUNT(*)
             FROM #tmp
         );

        -- Apply paging to temporary table, and output results
        SELECT
            *,
            @COUNT [Count]
        FROM #tmp
        WHERE ROWNUM > @lFirstRecord
            AND ROWNUM < @lLastRecord
        ORDER BY ROWNUM ASC;
        DROP TABLE #tmp;
```